# How to center an isometric grid on a background with CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A few months ago I vigorously started to create my own HTML/JS based game but since I ran into a few more challenging problems, progress has stopped completely.
One of these problems is as follows:

[image]

I have this grid of `div`s with `transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);` which I can't figure out how to keep centered on the background for various screen sizes.

The background image is decently centered with this:

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

My problem is that the grid should be centered like the background image and stick to it.

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFL2d/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should center it for a minimum of 400px width and height:

```
#grid {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    /*the following 4 definitions will center any div that uses absolute positioning*/
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top:-200px;/*1/2 of the height*/
    margin-left:-200px;/*1/2 of the width*/
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) skew(15deg, 15deg);

  background-size: 100% 100%;*/
}
```

Basically the trick to position a div in the center to use negative margin-left and margin-right, while assigning 1/2 of the width/height to them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes that actually does! Feel kind of stupid overlooking that. Now I only need to figure out how to keep the grid sticky when the background starts zooming.

Comment: @Jonathan it's one of those css tricks that don't show in any manual...:)

Comment: Lol, I've used it before but for some reason the skewed box skewed my mind.

Comment: Yeah it's all those patterns they'll hypnotize you be carefull! Feel free to mark as correct answer as I thrive on green arrows lol :)

Comment: Sure, any chance though you know how to replace the 400px with a dynamic scale?

Comment: @Jonathan btw I think that the the key to make the grid 'fixed' is not to set it to a pixel-based dimensions, but percentage based. I'll try to fiddle with it.

Comment: @Jonathan what's the ratio you want to keep between the html and the grid?

Comment: Thanks, about what you see in the picture.

Comment: @Jonathan unfortuntaly I don't have the time to play with it, have you read this article - http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46177/discussion-between-jonathan-and-yani)